# RMMapView or MGLMapView

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Should I be using Mapbox-iOS-SDK or Mapbox. I ask because I cannot seem to find much information on MGLMapView Currently It crashes randomly on startup without any consistency (issues related to threading and pointers)and when I am able to load the map I attempt to use mapView.styleID which causes an instant error shown bellow.(MapID taken from random style uploaded to account from Mapbox Editor). I seem to find more information on RMMapView. It should be noted I am using xcode 7 with Swift 2.0

```
 [ERROR] {Map}[Setup]: loading style failed: HTTP status code 404
```

Just as an added I need styled maps and directions from one point on the map to another

Answer (score 2):

Crashes are a separate issue over in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929157/mapbox-occasional-threading-errors. To be useful, we would need crash logs that show what crash is happening and in which thread.

Regarding the 404, it looks like you are actually using a `mapID`, not a `styleID`, meaning trying to send a source of raster imagery tiles to a place designed for a vector style source.

Currently, in order to use styles generated with Mapbox Studio or the Mapbox Editor, you want something like this:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-ios/examples/raster-styles/